# Adding some C executables to my Yocto build

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, yocto, yocto-recipe

I have created a layer that adds custom application code to a yocto layer we created. We have our code packaged into a tar.gz which we extract in two folders, /home/root/ and /home/data. The tar.gz contains a bunch of python code, bash scripts and C executables.

Our current script is doing a good job of extracting the tar file, creating the root and data files, copying the contents to their respective locations and copying the root.tar.gz to the home folder.

However, we've noticed that the C executables are getting modified. Their checksum and sizes are not matching up. We're looking for some advice on how to copy the C executables but we haven't found anything related to our issue yet.

Here's our .bb file.

```sh
DESCRIPTION = "Example Hello, World application for Yocto build."
SECTION = "examples"
DEPENDS = "libdigiapix"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend :="${THISDIR}/src:"

SRC_URI = "file://root.tar.gz "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit useradd
inherit allarch
USERADD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"
USERADD_PARAM_${PN} = "-u 1200 -d /home/data -r -s /bin/bash data"

do_install() {
install -d ${D}${ROOT_HOME}
install -d -m 755 ${D}/home/data
install -m 755 ${THISDIR}/src/root.tar.gz ${D}/home
chown -R data ${D}/home/data
cp --preserve=mode,timestamps -R ${WORKDIR}/root/* ${D}${ROOT_HOME}
cp --preserve=mode,timestamps -R ${WORKDIR}/data/* ${D}/home/data
}

FILES_${PN} += "${ROOT_HOME}/* /home/* /home/data/*"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT = "1"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "bash"
```

Directory structure -

```
. └── customapp
    ├── customapp.bb
    └── src
        └── root.tar.gz
```

2 directories, 2 files

Note : the files within the tar.gz seem unaffected. It's just the files that are extracted are facing this issue

So I tried inheriting allarch and it seems like the executables have some dependencies on librt.so.1 libc.so.6 but i don't want these files to be executed

Answer (score 0):

What problem is being caused by the files being manipulated? They can be stripped, prelinked, or more.

Comment: So when we setup the device there's a checksum mismatch between the expected values and what we're getting within the image. That's causing a few problems.
Is there any way we can prevent any kind of manipulation during this process?

Comment: Try ensuring you've turned off the prelink image feature and set INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP=1 in the recipe.

Comment: So I tried adding inherit allarch into it and it  seems like the executables have some dependencies, are are maybe being recompiled? I just want to copy them into location

Comment: Why would you inherit allarch?  Did you try what I said?

Comment: Yes, i did but it didn't make a difference. Also I have some space constraints so I can't risk increasing the image size using INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP=1